# KitchenAid dishwasher not responding/requiring cold reboot

Tags: electrical, appliances

I recently purchased a KitchenAid dishwasher (model KDTE334GPS0) to replace my old dishwasher. It is on a dedicated 15 amp circuit.

It randomly will not respond to button pushes. When I check the breaker, it isn't ever tripped, but I need to manually trip the breaker (cold reboot) in order for the buttons to start responding again. I would like to troubleshoot the issue a little before I reach out to an electrician. What could be causing the dishwasher to stop responding but not trip the breaker?

## EDIT

I checked the power going into the appliance when the buttons are unresponsive, and there is power.  I believe that rules out the breaker being bad.

Comment: Sounds a bit like a loose connection. Did anyone change any outlets? Does it have a GFCI?

Comment: Does the dishwasher have any lights or display that would prove whether it has power while the buttons are non-responsive? I have a hard time imagining that toggling a circuit breaker will fix a loose ac mains connection, but it's easy to believe that will reset buggy software in the dishwasher. If the problem is software an electrician won't be able to help. You may need an appliance service person and/or a warranty claim against the manufacturer.

Comment: @GregHill, I don't know if there is any lights that work when the buttons are non-responsive. I'll check the actual line next time it's acting funny

Comment: @joe_coolish Did you find a solution?  Im having exactly the same problem with the exact same model dishwasher.

Comment: @youcantexplainthat Yes, it was the control board. We had a technician come out and replace it. It was covered under warrantee so we didn't pay anything for the repair. We contacted kitchen aid directly to set everything up. I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 1):

How old is the circuit breaker? I had similar problems in the past where an outlet or appliance wasn't working and the breaker appeared to be open, only to find out it in fact was tripped. I could reset it, but in a short time , I would have the same problem. It turned out that the breaker was old and weak. It would appear to be open, but with the slightest touch, it would trip. Does it take a bit of effort to trip (turn off) the breaker when you reset it? If not, then a new breaker may be the solution.

Comment: I believe the breaker is 20 yro.  Is that old?  The tripping force for this breaker isn't any different than other breakers.  I'll check w/ my multimeter if this is the case though!  good thought

Comment: 20 years is a long time

Comment: Of course it didn't do it until today, then it did it twice!  I'll add this to the main topic as well, but there is still power going to the dish washer, so it isn't the breaker.  The appliance becomes unresponsive randomly, and not necessarily during a cycle. Any ideas?